# jquery tablesorter - alpha numeric sort priority

Tags: tablesorter

I have a table of race results http://bhaa.ie/events/eircom-2014 where the age category and position with the age category is displayed on a single column. The age categories have values SM,35M,40M,....,85M. The p0x represents the runners position within that category.

```
SM p01
35M p01
SM p02
45M p01
```

The default sorting at the moment give a preference to the 35 categoty, ie

```
35M p01
45M p01
SM p01
SM p02
```

I would prefer for the SM (ie Senior Men) to appear first in the sort order

```
SM p01
SM p02  
35M p01
45M p01
```

Is this possible with the jQuery tablesorter?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [custom parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html) for sorting, like this:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    id: 'age', 
    is: function(s) { 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) {
        return (s === 'SM' ? 0 : parseInt(s.replace('M', ''), 10));
    }, 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            0: { 
                sorter:'age' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Full code is available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34r8sy1z/1/).
Click on the `t0` header to see sorting in action

Answer (score 0):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can set the [`stringTo` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#stringto) to `min` to force the alphabetical characters to always sort before the lowest number ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4091/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        stringTo: "min",
        headers: {
            4: {
                sorter: 'digit'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also, the `headers` option is set to ensure that the column is set to use the number parser instead of the text parser as "S" is in the first row and that column is therefore detected as a text column.